# Grails:display results in gsp

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy, gsp

I have 3 domains classes

```
Class Application { 
    Candidate candidate;
    Vote vote;
    static belongsTo = [candidate:Candidate,vote:Vote]

}

Class Candidate {
    String username;
    static hasMany =[capplications:Application]
}

Class Vote {
    String name;
    Date startdate;
    Date enddate;
    static hasMany =[capplications:Application]

}
```

I have a service class that contains a method that displays the names of votes

```
class  ApplicationService {

    def serviceMethod() {
    }


    def candidatesByVName(def vname){
        def results = Candidature.createCriteria().list() {
            createAlias("candidat","candidatAlias")
            createAlias("vote","voteAlias")
            eq('voteAlias.name',vname)
            projections {
                // property('votes.name')
                property('candidatAlias.username')
            }
        }
        return results
    }
    def candidatsGrpByVte(){

        def results = Application.withCriteria {
            createAlias("vote", "vote")
            projections {
                groupProperty("vote.name")
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

I started in the controller

```
class ApplicationController{
    def applicationService;
    def displayVote={
        def votes=applicationService.candidatsGrpByVte()
        return [VoteList:votes]
    }
    def displayCandByVote={
        def candidate=applicationService.candidatesByVName(params.vote)
    }
}
```

I want to display the list of candidates for each vote in a view

Answer (score 0):

first, you shouldn't use both field references and belongsTo for the same relations (candidate and vote) in your Application class - it's redundant

second, you should avoid defs where it's possible, so if you know that your service method returns a list, declare it as returning List, not def (it helps your IDE)

third, your displayCandByVote action does not return a map, though it should if you want to display it - otherwise you will not be able to reference in your gsp, e.g.

ApplicationController.groovy:

```
class ApplicationController{
    ...
    def displayCandByVote={
        def candidate=applicationService.candidatesByVName(params.vote)
        return [candidates: candidate]
    }
}
```

/views/application/displayCandByVote.gsp:

```
<ul>
<g:each in="${ candidates }">
    <li>${ it }</li>
</g:each>
</ul>
```